# Lightswitch HTML "could not find property"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

While creating a browse data screen in Lightswitch we get the following error when deploying the screen:'

> Could not find a property named 'event' on type
>   'LightSwitchApplication.category'. Inner exception message: Could not
>   find a property named 'event' on type
>   'LightSwitchApplication.category'.

The property is included in the SQL database and also imported to the Linq Lightswitch database.

How do i fix this problem?

Comment: Could you include the code behind?